# Batch file copy from undefined directory

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to copy `test` and `test1` folder under `%%e ("QA_ENDORSEMENT")` since the folder name is varying.

[image: filename QA_ENDORSEMENT sometimes varies]

But I cannot get it done using my code below.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%e in (`dir /b C:\BACKUPS\UAT`) do (
    xcopy "C:\BACKUPS\UAT\%%e\*" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\" /F /E)
```

Comment: are you trying to copy only specific folders or all folders in a directory?

Comment: are you basically looking at copying everything from ` C:\BACKUPS\UAT\QA_ENDORSEMENT\` or just folders `test` and `test1` from `QA_ENDOREMENT`

Comment: I am trying to copy all folders under QA_ENDORSEMENT. but QA_ENDORSEMENT is varying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will copy anything within `C:\BACKUPS\UAT\*\`

So if you have `C:\BACKUPS\UAT\QA_ENDORSEMENT\test` it will copy `test` and its subdirectories and files to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`
but if you have `C:\BACKUPS\UAT\ANOTHER\anotherfolder` it will also copy `anotherfolder` and its sub directories to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`

```
for /f %%e in ('dir /b C:\BACKUPS\UAT\*') do (xcopy "C:\BACKUPS\UAT\%%e\*" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\" /Y /F /E)
```

Basically you will copy anything inside the subfolders of `C:\BACKUPS\UAT\*` but excluding the actual `QA_ENDORSEMENT` directory or others in `UAT` themselves.

Comment: what if QA_ENDORSEMENT is not always the folder name?

Comment: @JoedSeverino: how does it differ? Completely random? Some fix string in the name?

Comment: That is why I asked the questions. The question is unclear. Do you want to always copy from QA_ENDORSMENT or from any folder in UAT?

Comment: @JoedSeverino Edited with other option. But as soon as I am clear to what you want, I will edit accordingly

Comment: I take it it was the second option. Will edit the answer to only include that.